# ggplot2: How to have a different color of geom_vline()

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

I have this five (5) geom_vline() in my plot and I want them to have a different colors. Is there a way to do that?

Here's my codes,

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(-7, 8, length = 90)
tvalues <- dt(x,15)

qplot(x, tvalues) + geom_polygon(fill = "purple", colour = "purple", alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(fill = "purple", colour = "purple", alpha = 0.2, pch = 21) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(a <- c(-2.27685371,  0.01661155,  
  0.33598194,  1.92426022), mean(a)), linetype = "dashed", colour = "red") + theme_bw() + xlab(bquote(bold('Average Tensile Strength (lb/in'^'2'*')'))) +
  ylab(expression(bold(P(x)))) +
  opts(title = expression(bold("Student t Distribution")), plot.title = theme_text(size = 20, colour = "darkblue"),
       panel.border = theme_rect(size = 2, colour = "red"))
```

And here is the output,

[image]

Notice the five vertical lines in the plot, I want each of those line to have a different color,

I tried this

```
library(colorRamps)
geom_vline(xintercept = c(a <- c(-2.27685371,  0.01661155,  
   0.33598194,  1.92426022), mean(a)), linetype = "dashed", colour = matlab.like(5))
```

but didn't work, Another attempt

```
geom_vline(xintercept = c(a <- c(-2.27685371,  0.01661155,  
   0.33598194,  1.92426022), mean(a)), linetype = "dashed", colour = c("red","blue","green","yellow","orange"))
```

and still unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So you're sort of missing the fundamental idea behind **ggplot2**, which is that you always put all your data into a `data.frame` and every aesthetic that you map corresponds to a variable in your data frame.

You could get 5 vertical lines, each of a different color with five separate calls to `geom_vline` but that misses the point of the entire package. Instead, you create a data frame:

```
a <- c(-2.27685371,0.01661155,0.33598194,1.92426022)
vlines <- data.frame(xint = c(a,mean(a)),grp = letters[1:5])
```

I've explicitly created a grouping variable `grp` to map to `colour`. Then we add the layer and map the aesthetics to these variables using `aes`:

```
qplot(x, tvalues) + 
  geom_polygon(fill = "purple", colour = "purple", alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(fill = "purple", colour = "purple", alpha = 0.2, pch = 21) +
  geom_vline(data = vlines,aes(xintercept = xint,colour = grp), linetype = "dashed") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  xlab(bquote(bold('Average Tensile Strength (lb/in'^'2'*')'))) +
  ylab(expression(bold(P(x)))) +
  opts(title = expression(bold("Student t Distribution")), 
       plot.title = theme_text(size = 20, colour = "darkblue"),
       panel.border = theme_rect(size = 2, colour = "red"))
```

(The colors will be hard to distinguish because they're dashed lines, and two of them are nearly on top of each other.)

You will get much more out of **ggplot2** if you transition away from `qplot` towards `ggplot()` and start putting your data into data frames rather than vectors.

Comment: Well, thanks for reminding that :) I should have thought of that. Thank you so much! you save my time :)

Comment: That is a great answer, it gave me the right direction on doing something similar. I needed to add geom_hlines to the mean of a plot with different groups. I did mean by group and used geom_hline as describe by you. The difference is that I've used "linetype = grp" to have different linetypes and it was inside the aes call, instead of being outside as shown here.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to put one line, adding the following `geom` would add a vertical line at `x=1` in red colour and dashed.

```
+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept=1), colour="#BB0000", linetype="dashed")
```